# data modelling in influxdb

Tags: data-modeling, influxdb

I would like to take your suggestion on data modelling in influxdb. I have vehicles which are producing a lot of values like soc, odometer, lat, lon etc.
I have 2 options that I see as modeling this data in influx

1) Create a single measurement as 'x' with tag as vehicle_id and various fields for this measurement like soc, odometer, lat, lon

2) Create multiple measurement as soc, odometer, lat, lon ... each as a tab vehicle_id

Which one would you prefer and why. 
I am using first one which seems to be a more natural approach.

Answer (score 1):

According to their official [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/key_concepts/#measurement), measurement is conceptually a table. fields are more like attributes under a single measurement. Because influxdb  is a columnar database, records/points are organised in a structure of series, where each series belongs to a set of a db, a measurement and field(s), with one or multiple field(s) as identifier.

To answer your question, if u would like to `join` multiple features for query, you should have put them as field(s) under one single measurement; if they have no inter-connection whatsoever, then put them as separate measurement would be more human-readable.

Moreover, theoretically, you can actually put everything into one single measurement with hundred field(s) and query with only the relevant fields. But this would create high cardinality which would put pressure on the read/write process. You would need to take care of high-cardinality through batching and cache on influxdb configuration. Therefore it is more read & write efficient to use as few fields as possible.

Comment: Cardinality depends on number of unique values in tags, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

In our case some of the devices we manage hold multiple data (e.g. GPS provides lat, lon, etc...) hence it felt natural to have one measurement for the device (GPS) and enclose the different values in fields. We add a tag for the vehicle id.

This approach also implies that there is no naming convention to be implemented in the fields name.

Please share what you finally used.

Comment: I am using the first approach. One measurement with lots of fields. It helps me writing complex queries very easily

Comment: Tags are easily filtered, I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Go with option 1.

It'll be easier to query use this data later.

eg, a single "vehicle" metric

```
+------------+-----+----------+-----+-----+
| vehicle_id | soc | odometer | lat | lon |
+------------+-----+----------+-----+-----+
| ac31b2ea31 |   ? |   123144 |  42 |  22 |
+------------+-----+----------+-----+-----+
```

Make the vehicle_id a [tag](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/METRICS.md), and the rest [fields](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/METRICS.md).

Keep in mind the more tags you have and the more unique values (aka "[cardinality](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/glossary/#series-cardinality)") there are in those tag values, [the larger and slower your index](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#q-how-can-i-manage-series-cardinality).

Comment: Yes I am using the same approach as I have a lot of queries where I need to filter based on multiple fields

Answer (score -1):

The cardinality problem is the same in both models, what counts towards the cardinality is the number of unique combinations of (measurement,tags,field) so splitting fields in measurements does not reduce cardinality.

What you should consider is the type of analysis you would like to perform on your data. Historically and I still think it is the case, InfluxQL could not do computations across measurements so splitting your various fields in separate measurements would prohibit you from doing some computations.

The tabular model is not the ideal approach when it comes to time series, it is better to consider each time series as a separate objet and leverage functions which can work on a set of series, this way no matter how you decided to organize your data in the storage layer, the analytics layer can make use of it.

Comment: field values do not contribute to cardinality.